# Show "virtual" folder in My Computer

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, savefiledialog, shell-extensions

My application connects to a service to send and receive data.  I have the option of allowing my users to store their application configuration on the host server in an xml document. This allows them to access their settings on multiple computers.  Ideally, I would like to give the users the option of saving to/loading from either the host system or a local file.  I envision doing this in a manner similar to when you browse your computer and see an outlook entry or PhotoStream.  This way, in the standard file save/file open dialog, they could browse up to My Computer and then select that folder.  As I am only able to save one XML document, ideally, they would just be able to click on that item as if it is a file.  Anyone have examples of something similar.  My research has led me to shell extensions, but not much matches my needs.

Comment: Look at shell *namespace* extensions.